# Unable to connect to GitHub API: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException

Tags: git, jenkins, github, pull-request

My Primary doubt is how github authentication happens in jenkins ?

Task: We have to establish connection in jenkins with github repo for "GitHub Pull Request Builder".

GitHub Auth
---->  GitHub Server API URL : https://api.github.com (Why we are giving this value ? We did not give any of repository name here, So, how authentication is happening?)
---->  credentials : I have given mine and tested with "connect to API", Response is: Connected to https://api.github.com as null (null) login: {{ my_user_name }}

----> But if i give my colleague credentials (which are already listed under credentials) and tested with "Connect to API" then below error has been coming.

Unable to connect to GitHub API: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: {"message":"Requires authentication","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#get-the-authenticated-user"

```
   GitHub Pull Request Builder
   GitHub Auth  
   GitHub Server API URL    https://api.github.com
   Help for feature: GitHub Server API URL
      Jenkins URL override  
   Help for feature: Jenkins URL override
   Shared secret    
   ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
   Help for feature: Shared secret
   Credentials  user_name/****** (github user)
   Add
   Help for feature: Credentials
   Test basic connection to GitHub          
   Error:       
       Connect to API
   Unable to connect to GitHub API: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: {"message":"Requiresauthentication","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#get-the-authenticated-user"}
```

Could someone please help on this ?

Answer (score 7):

I found out, how you do it. Basically Jenkins doesn't like different access tokens in global and Job specific Authentication.

1. Go to "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System" > Scroll down to GitHub
2. "Add Github Server" with API URL "https://api.github.com"
3. As Credentials use your Personal Access Token from github as "Secret Text"
4. Click "Test Connection" to verify it works.
5. (optional) enable "Manage hooks" if you like
6. "Save"/"Apply"
7. Now you can go and setup the Github Organization in Jenkins, where you ->
8. specifiy the the credentials as "Username with password", where username is your github username and password your personal access token. ID and description may be empty but could help to remember what the credentials are for.
9. Make sure you set the "Owner" value correctly to a github profile your account has access to. (e.g. the same name as specified in the credentials)
10. Configure the remainder of the github organization as you like
11. "Save"/"Apply"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your username and password. It doesn't work. Use a Personal access token from your Github account and use it as a secret text credential with Jenkins.

Comment: It is not possible to use anything else! You are forced to use Username+Password. The dscription mentions to enter the personal access token as password, but the issue still persists ...

Comment: A few weeks back I used the personal access token method. Have you tried what you're saying here?

Comment: Yes. I was literally in the process of setting up my Jenkins instance and configuring the GitHub Organization, when I stumbled upon the issue of not being able to just use the secret text for the Personal Access Token.

Comment: I followed the process. No issues for me. What's the Jenkins version that you use?

Answer (score 0):

In my case here in 2023, I tried following @Pingger Shikkoken's answer, though unfortunately it didnt' work.

What solved it for me was going to "Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Github" and just adding a new Github Server with the same settings (my API token was already up to date).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34535729)

Answer (score -1):

While connecting to github, you need to give credentials. For `GitHub Pull Request Builder`, you need to use access token for setting up credentials for a given Github Server API Url. Authentication is done based on your access token.

When you are creating a job, at that time you are required to give your `github url`. A job will be created for that particular github repository.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin).

Comment: Thanks @Nisarg Shah,

I have few doubts , could you answer?

 1. How do i know the 'GitHub Server API URL" if it is enterprise github.
 2. Usind the token "I'm able to clone the git repo", where as , if i want to configure 'pull request builder' in configure system using the same token is giving the below error.

Unable to connect to Github API: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException:{"message":"Bad Credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}

Im unable to understand where im missing the logic.

Comment: I think for "GitHub Server API URL", there would be some special kind of endpoints, I am not sure about that. For connecting to "Pull request builder", you need to follow steps mentioned here : https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin#credentials in your jenkins